# csv file input processing using logstash stops working after 2/3 days

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash-1.5.1 to process csv file and get upload into elasticsearch-1.5.1.This process should happen for every day.So I put my logstash and elastic search engines up once and left it hoping that csv file processing should happen for every day and get uploaded into elasticsearch.Every day one new csv file is being downloaded from internet and get stored in local folder from where logstash reads. But surprisingly the logstash stop processing the csv file after 2/3 days.I don't know the reason please help me . The logstash input file configuration is as follows.

```
input { 

    file {
        type => "csv"
        path => "D:/Tools/logstash-1.5.1/data/**/*"
        start_position => beginning
        sincedb_path => "D:/Tools/logstash-1.5.1/sincedb/.sincedb"
    }

}


filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
      }

    }


output {
  elasticsearch { 
    host => "localhost" 
    cluster => "Test"
    node_name => "data"
    index => "client"
    template => "D:/Tools/logstash-1.5.1/lib/elasticsearch-template.json"
    template_overwrite => true

  }

}
```

Comment: I suggest you add `--debug` to your logstash command line so you can share more insights on what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

So, try to use logstash-forwarder and please post result, I am really interesting in it.
You can install logstash-forwarder with, for example, this configuration:

```
{
  "network": {
    "servers": [ "$YOUR_SERVER:$PORT" ],
    "timeout": 20,
    "ssl ca": "/path/to/logstash/*.crt_file"
             },

  "files": [
       {
        "paths": ["D:/Tools/logstash-1.5.1/data/**/*"],
        "fields": { "type": "csv" },
        "dead time" : "5m"
     }
   ]
}
```

And in your logstash server you can use this input:

```
input {
   lumberjack {
         port => "$PORT"
         ssl_key => "/path/to/your/*.key_file"
         ssl_certificate => " "/path/to/your/*.key_file""
         }
}
```

Comment: I provided the entire logstash config file in the question

Comment: Fast decision, that I can offer  - use logstash-forwarder. It is good for processing events from files and paths with wildcards. For me this works really good.

Comment: Thank you Eddy for your help . I implemented your solution and left it for testing . Hoping that Logstash - Elastic search combo will run continuously

Comment: No problem @sagar - I am glad it works. I want to add some advices:  
- If logstash's pipeline is blocked just restart it  
- To avoid manual restarts you can write cronjob to restart logstash once a day  
- If logstash's process stops working with no reason, check output configuration. If your output is to ES AND to stdout too, then disable stdout output. This is a bug.